# XAML: How to set controls properties depending on screen resolution?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm developing WPF application (.NET 4) where I have few UserControl's which looks pretty good on most of the screens.

But now customer have new monitors where some elements are too small. The best solution we found is to make some elements smaller, to left more space for the main panel.

The layout is now pretty complex, and I spend a lot of time to find which margins, heights, widths and so on.. I need to change to implement this.

Usually it is some children elements Height, Width +-10 or so. Sometimes Margin. And in one case it's Style's Setter Property="Width" which defined in Resources.

I'm wondering is it possible to make this changes configurable, so for my specified screen resolution (let's say I know only that Width=X and Height=Y) they was applied, and for all other screens it stays the same as now?

How to do this using as less code-behind as possible?

I like the solution with VisualStateManager and VisualState.SateTriggers, but looks like my application does not recognize this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using user controls inside the window may be you could set the height and width of the grid's row and column definition to '*' and also make scroll bar visibility of horizontal and vertical scroll bar to auto.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said, layout is too complicated, there are not simply rows and grids. There are icons, texts, backgrounds and who knows what else it could be.